# Safari screen confirmation in development with VPN and Remote Desktop

Tags: angular, safari, vpn, remote-desktop

I am developing angular on Windows remotely using a VPN and Remote Desktop set up by MAC. I would like to view the angular application running on localhost: 4200 on the remote connection in Safari on my MAC, but I don't know how to view the application launched on windows on the remote connection in Safari on my MAC. Please give me an advise.